# Послать данные с камеры на rtmp-сервер(ActionScript)

Tags: flash, rtmp, actionscript

Подскажите пожалуйста где можно найти листинг простейшего кода для захвата данных с камеры и отправки их в реальном времени на rtmp-сервер.

С флешом в первый раз начал работать, добился лишь того что камера включается на 1 снимок и посылает его. Пробовал слать данные через setInterval(fun, 20), так получаются огромные задержки да и вообще как-то не правильно это.

Answer (score 1):

Гугл.

https://www.google.com.ua/#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=as3+rtmp+webcam

Конкретный пример.

http://www.endseven.net/as3-introduction-to-rtmp-streaming-publishing